# Issue with declaring Int and calculation with decimals

Tags: decimal

First of all, thank you for your help! I'm fairly new to coding and I am having trouble with my app calculating when decimals are entered into the text field. It allows whole numbers no problem, but I would like to be able to enter decimals.

Thank you!
Here is what I have so far. Looking for help on when I go to calculate the score. Using SwiftUI

```
@State var value1: String = ""
@State var value2: String = ""
@State var value3: String = ""
@State var score: String = ""
@State var scoredetail: String = ""



            VStack {
                TextField("Enter value1", text: $value1)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                   

                TextField("Enter value2", text: $value2)
                   

                TextField("Enter value3", text: $value3)
                  




            VStack {
                Text(score)
                    
                Text(scoredetail)
                   


        }

        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                let value1 = Int(self.value1)
                let value2 = Int(self.value2)
                let value3 = Int(self.value3)
                                                    
                let finalscore = Int((value1! * value2!) / (value3!))
              
               
                self.score = "Your score is"
                if finalscore > 18{
                    self.scoredetail = "A+ Value"
```

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, you should specify in post or tag, but it's clear that you're using Integer (Int) values for calculation and will thus get Integer results. In your Button(action: section use your languages equivalent of Single or Double to get the decimal point values. You might also want to explore your language for conversion functions that will convert the strings to the required type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was able to change that to fix my issue. And I will modify the post to denote SwiftUI.

Comment: let value1 = Double(self.value1)
                    let value2 = Double(self.value2)
                    let value3 = Double(self.value3)                                                             
                    let finalscore = (Double((value1! * value2!)) / (value3!))